# How can I tell if the list order changed when I sort by different properties of the list?

Tags: python

If I have a list of dicts and I sort the list by two different keys, how can I tell if the resulting list order is the same for both keys?

For instance I have a list such as:

```
rename_operations = [
    {'before_rename': 'DSCF_1.jpg', 'after_rename': '20181200_123112.jpg'},
    {'before_rename': 'DSCF_2.jpg', 'after_rename': '20181200_123212.jpg'},
    {'before_rename': 'DSCF_3.jpg', 'after_rename': '20181200_123312.jpg'},
    {'before_rename': 'DSCF_4.jpg', 'after_rename': '20181200_123412.jpg'},
    {'before_rename': 'DSCF_5.jpg', 'after_rename': '20181200_123512.jpg'},
]
```

I want to validate that in both cases sorting the list by `before_rename` and by `after_rename` yields the list in the same order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can just use `==`

```
rename_operations1 = [
    {'before_rename': 'DSCF_1.jpg', 'after_rename': '20181200_123112.jpg'},
    {'before_rename': 'DSCF_2.jpg', 'after_rename': '20181200_123212.jpg'},
    {'before_rename': 'DSCF_3.jpg', 'after_rename': '20181200_123312.jpg'},
    {'before_rename': 'DSCF_4.jpg', 'after_rename': '20181200_123412.jpg'},
    {'before_rename': 'DSCF_5.jpg', 'after_rename': '20181200_123512.jpg'},
]

rename_operations2 = [
    {'before_rename': 'DSCF_1.jpg', 'after_rename': '20181200_123112.jpg'},
    {'before_rename': 'DSCF_3.jpg', 'after_rename': '20181200_123312.jpg'},
    {'before_rename': 'DSCF_4.jpg', 'after_rename': '20181200_123412.jpg'},
    {'before_rename': 'DSCF_5.jpg', 'after_rename': '20181200_123512.jpg'},
    {'before_rename': 'DSCF_2.jpg', 'after_rename': '20181200_123212.jpg'},
]

print(rename_operations1 == rename_operations2)
>>> False

print(rename_operations1 == rename_operations1)
>>> True
```